# How can I power an Arduino with high voltage (400 V)?

Tags: arduino, voltage-divider, high-voltage, voltage-measurement, isolation

I need to power Arduino that is used in pre-charge circuitry for an electric vehicle. The Arduino will monitor the battery and controller voltage. The peak battery voltage is 400 V.

I want to ask whether I can power it through a potential divider from the high-voltage battery and use a linear regulator ahead to power the Arduino from the high voltage for isolation purposes and high-voltage ground to monitor voltages. What will be the issues with that?

P.S I have looked into DC/DC converters and isolation amplifiers as well. I just want an easier and cheaper way.

Comment: "I want an easier and cheaper way": no. Not when 400V in a vibrating car under potentially strenous thermal conditions are involved. This is just unnecessarily dangerous.

Comment: BEVs have a 12v battery for this reason. Use the 12v to power the electronics.

Comment: sounds like a good way to void the vehicle warranty

Comment: Sounds like the number one issue will be touch safety for the user. 400 V can give you a pretty bad shock. If the entire assembly can be isolated from the user as a high voltage component, then it may be feasible.

Comment: _"... a linear regulator ahead to power the Arduino from high voltage for isolation purpose ..."_ - I'm unsure how you mean this, but to be sure: you're aware a linear voltage regulator does not offer isolation?

Comment: @mkeith _"400 V can give you a pretty bad shock."_ - I think that's an understatement; 400VDC is very dangerous.

Comment: Any short over a 400V source is going to instantly immolate almost anything. Great way to start a fire or burn yourself.

Comment: @marcelm yes. Death cannot be ruled out.

Comment: I wonder if a quality phone charger cube has enough margin to operate from 400VDC.

Comment: As @user1850479 pointed out, EVs are commonly equipped with a 12V battery to power low-voltage electronics. Use that to supply the Arduino.

Comment: DEATH AND/OR DISASTER ARE NEAR CERTAIN IF A NON ISOLATED SYSTEM IS USED. Use of a divider is an extremely bad idea.  Isolated converters are available (although not overly common).  An unusual approa h with better efficiency than a divider and not as good as a converter would be to use LEDs driving photovoltaic cells. The difficulty of driving LEDS at 400V is less than that if staying alive with a non isolated syste.m

Comment: A safe but not wise system would be a resistor driving a low voltage isolated converter with attention paid to the isolation capability. This is quite possibly the easiest approach tht is anything like sane. | Another method that would work but has obvious drawbacks is using a 400v motor driving a low voltage alternator using a suitable insulated shaft.

Comment: This is exactly what you want albeit far far far more power capable. It shows both how easy and how hard it is.
https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tiduey2/tiduey2.pdf?ts=1666525341811&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F

Comment: @Bryan no but there are little SMPS specced for 430VDC, see my answer

Comment: @user1850479 that's not true. It's because lithium batteries will die irreplaceably after the voltage goes beyond the threshold. The old Tesla Roadster uses the Lithium-ion also for powering electronics, and after [a guy needs $40000 to replace it after parking for too long Tesla began to add the 12V lead acid battery](https://provscons.com/why-does-tesla-have-a-12v-battery/). But newer Teslas also [don't have the lead acid battery anymore](https://electrek.co/2021/02/02/tesla-model-s-x-get-rid-lead-acid-12v-battery-moves-li-ion/)

Comment: @phuclv That's an article about Tesla's new 12v batteries. Sounds to me like they're still using 12v batteries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

both through the linear regulator and through the top resistor of your voltage divider, the full current for your arduino needs to flow. Let's say that's 50 mA. So, your whole circuit is converting 400V·50mA = 20 W into heat.

Now, you need to have at least tens time that current flowing through your voltage divider to make it not look like a variably loaded diver, so 200W.

You will need a massive active cooling system for this, *even* if we're just talking 20 W (find a 20W incandescent bulb. Turn it on, wait 5 minutes, then touch it. You will know why this is problematic.)

Your solution is not only worse in safety, size and stability, but also much heavier, larger and far more expensive than doing it safely.

Comment: Followup question. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/639609/measuring-high-voltage-dc-using-an-arduino

Answer (score 6):

**What peak current does the Arduino take in full operation?**

You have to work at providing that answer.

However...

If the Arduino takes (say) 100 mA then the resistor you add needs to drop something like 390 volts at 100 mA hence, the resistor needed is 3.9 kΩ. Unfortunately, the power dissipated by the resistor will be 39 watts and this is a bad idea (given that you want a cheap and easy way).

On the other hand, if the maximum current is 25 mA, the resistor will need to be 15.6 kΩ and will dissipate nearly 10 watts.

Do you see the problem of dropping a voltage with a resistor? This is why we use DC-DC converter circuits.

Comment: Followup question
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/639609/measuring-high-voltage-dc-using-an-arduino

Comment: @pingpong you didn't read the instructions left by Sam Gibson correctly. No need to mention anything here; you need to refer back to **this question** from within your newer question.

Answer (score 5):

Most low power AC-DC switching power supplies without PFC are built with a filter, then a diode bridge to rectify mains voltage, and a filter cap. They will work find with DC at the input instead of AC.

In addition, it provides much needed isolation. So your arduino will be connecte to battery ground at the correct place for sensing voltage, that wire won't carry current, that will avoid a ground loop and many other problems.

230V AC has a peak voltage of 322V, so a power supply specified for 230V AC should work with up to 322V DC. This is too low for your application, so please don't use any random USB charger.

The DC voltage to use when searching for a power supply is the maximum fully charged battery voltage, not the nominal voltage.

You can go to [mouser](https://www.mouser.fr/c/power/power-supplies/ac-dc-power-modules/) and use the filter to find power supplies with acceptable input voltage. For example, [this one from CUI](https://www.mouser.fr/ProductDetail/CUI-Inc/PSK-5D-5?qs=DRkmTr78QASBDZkT%252BYmSQQ%3D%3D) will input up to 430V DC and deliver 5V 1A, with a no-load power consumption of less than 0.1W, decent efficiency above 75%, and a very reasonable price. It is a reputable manufacturer, and it sure beats rolling your own both on cost and safety.

Note any linear solution would have an efficiency of 5V/400V=1.25% to be compared to a 75% efficient switching power supply.

You will absolutely need a fuse rated for 400V DC against fire hazard.

Note this project is firmly in the "kill yourself" category, anything involving high voltage batteries is extremely deadly. Unlike mains there is no RCD to save you, and the peak current can be high enough to vaporize hand tools, so make sure to wear safety glasses. No offense, but if you have to ask if it's a good idea to use a voltage divider to power an arduino in this situation, I would recommend getting some help, for your safety.

The voltage sense wiring also carries deadly voltage, and it must also be fused. I'd recommend putting the high side resistor of the voltage divider right where the high voltage is sensed, not on your PCB, because its high value will limit current in the wire and make it much less dangerous. Make sure to use proper shrouded connectors that don't leave conductors exposed to fingers or short to chassis, if there is high voltage on the PCB, put an insulating sheet below it, etc. Clean, vibration resistant wiring is a must, tie wraps, heatshrink, etc.

I find it highly unlikely that the vehicle would not offer a source of a more civilized voltage like 5-12V to run the electronic equimpent, so it may be simpler to use this instead, although you may then get a ground loop and have to use a differential amplifier.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/639609/measuring-high-voltage-dc-using-an-arduino

Comment: @pingpong, if this or other answers provide what you need for this question, please reward those who took the time and effort to provide it, by choosing it as an accepted answer. This is an important mechanism to improve the reputation of those who help you, and provides incentive for those who might answer your "follow-up" question.... I see you did as requested. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The typical way that things like this are handled is that you have a VERY low quiescent current circuit powered from the high voltage. If you can get your arduino power consumption low enough, then you can use this approach. Sometimes you may have a "sleep" state that is very low quiescent current, and then a slightly higher power regulator that is turned on only when awake. Then turned off again during "sleep." But a low-quiescent linear regulator is powered on at all times. You would want the sleep-state current to be 100 uA or less, most likely. Other people have explained why 20 mA is too much current to use a linear regulator or voltage divider + linear regulator.

NOTE: the ENTIRE circuit MUST be properly protected from user contact since a 400 VDC bus can potentially cause a lethal electric shock. There can be no wires and no buttons etc., that lead to any kind of user interface or other low-voltage device. If there are any buttons or wires, then careful attention must be paid to proper isolation and labeling for service personnel.

You have to make sure you don't accidentally kill somebody with this.