# Measuring high voltage DC using an Arduino

Tags: arduino, power, high-voltage, voltage-measurement, isolation

I want to measure a high voltage DC (electric vehiclr battery pack) source with isolation. The 4 ways I identified were using

1. Linear optocoupler
2. Isolated amplifier
3. ADC on the HV side and sending the voltage digitally to LV side with optical isolation
4. Using a voltage to frequency/pwm convertor

The first two options are too expensive/complicated for me so that only leaves me with the latter two.

For the third option I was thinking of stepping down the HV DC (~400 V) to 5 V using an SMPS to power the Arduino. I wanted to know if I were to use a voltage divider with the HV DC to measure the voltage using the Arduino ADC would I run into problems with ground reference? i.e the SMPS ground is different from the HV DC ground and as such the Arduino ADC has a different reference ground?L.

The fourth option seems the easiest to me but I was having the same confusion as above. Will the V to F IC be powered by the HV side? Can I use a voltage divider to step down the voltage to 5 V and use a voltage regulator IC such as an LM7805 and power it using that? V to F ICs have very low power requirements (50 - 10 mW) so the power loss in the potential divider resistor will be very low.

I would also like to know if there are any easier methods to measure HV DC with isolation.

Comment: pingpong - Hi, This is clearly a follow-on from [your last question](/q/639518). However that one cannot now be changed (as it has received answers) to this next version. Therefore to avoid annoying people by having 2 related questions open at the same time, where the previous one is now obsolete & partly duplicates this one: Please *strongly* consider [áccepting](/help/accepted-answer) an answer to that previous question, as that is the only way we have to indicate that a question is effectively solved/closed. Then [edit] this question to link to that one & explain how this one is different.

Comment: Can we finally lay down the resistor divider idea? It's still not appropriate, as you certainly can see from both the answers to your previous question. 50 mW at 5V means 10 mA – and across 395 V voltage difference, that means 4W of heat that you do in a resistors.

Comment: If I were to power the adc or v to f with an isolated smps source would I have problems measuring the hv voltage (scaled down to 1v with a potential divider 4M Ohm and 1k R sense so 10 uamps) cause of the ics having a different ground ?

Comment: @pingpong who is that addressed to? Or should it be a new question? Or a comment somewhere else?

Comment: I addressed you sorry for the confusion @MarcusMüller

Comment: then I'm confused what this is about? I commented on the resistor divider solution only here. Is this maybe really a new question you want to ask?

Comment: Dont forget you can supply isolated power from LV side. Easier than stepping 400V down to 5V/3.3V to power some ADCs/MCUs/etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can I use a voltage divider to step down the voltage to 5 V and use a voltage regulator IC such as an LM7805 and power it using that. […] V to F ics have very low power requirements (50 - 10 mW) so the power loss in the potential divider resistor will be very low.

No. Please. This was already answered in your previous question: the fact that your load "only" uses little power at 5V means that you still need to supply all its current through your voltage divider and your linear regulator. In the comments I calculated that for you – 4W get continuously dropped over your resistor. Such resistors exist, but you will have to pay for that power resistor (effectively, a small incandescent light bulb's equivalent of power, only that you don't want the resistor to glow in white light) and you will have to cool it actively.  Nothing about this is "easy".

If you actually want to build a voltage divider out of two resistors to then feed your 5V regulator and keep the voltage within that regulator's input range, you will need to spend more than 10 times power on the voltage divider. Honestly, we shouldn't even have to discuss this if you're measuring voltages: This is basics, P = U·I.

> I was thinking of stepping down the hv DC (~400 V) to 5 V using an smps

An appropriate approach!

> I wanted to know if I were to use a voltage divider with the HV DC to measure the voltage using the Arduino ADC would I run into problems with ground reference

No, if you're doing this all on the side that referenced to your high-voltage ground, that seems the way to go.

> 1. linear optocoupler
> 2. isolated amplifier
> 3. having an ADC at the hv side and sending the voltage digitally to LV side with optical isolation
> 4. Using a voltage to frequency/pwm convertor

### Linear Optocoupler

… or any optocoupler, really, that comes with a sufficiently specified input/output-current curve, since applying a corrective curve is trivial in a microcontroller:

Would be an easy, low-complexity solution. Problem: These things are extremely temperature dependent, so you would need to find a way to stabilize its temperature, or to accurately measure its temperature. I bet there's measurement-grade optoisolators that have temperature control or correction built in, but these will cost more...

### Isolated amplifier

- Needs supply on HV side
- costly

### Measure on HV side, send optically to isolated side

That's how I'd do it. Still needs a HV-side supply, but that can be cheaply built using SMPS.

There's dedicated isolated ADCs for exactly such measurement problems; e.g. https://www.digikey.com/short/dr0tf0ww . Of course, these cost like 7€, but they save you a HV-side microcontroller and thus reduce complexity of your overall system.

### Voltage-to-Frequency converter

If you want, just "half an ADC" (this is especially true if you think about how Delta-Sigma ADCs work). Sure, that works. I guess the idea was to then transport the AC through a transformer to achieve isolation, or at least through class Y capacitors.

Will work, depends on the accuracy of your conversion. Many V-to-F converters are not so good, and the ones that don't look like fake or counterfeit chips on ebay are currently pretty expensive (3,50€ for the cheapest one you can actually buy from digikey, AD7740, but that's also actually a pretty good V-to-F converter, so that's an upside). So that you'd be better off doing the conversion with the ADC of some MCU and letting the MCU then generate a square wave of desired frequency (or some PWM of desired length); might just as well let the MCU then send the data using UART across an optical isolator. (If you can keep the output zero-mean, can also use capacitors or transformers instead an optical isolator). Or, might directly go for the isolated ADC.

Comment: Thank you for your help , I have decided to use an isolated adc to read the voltages as it is safer and easier than the other methods even if it costs a bit more compared to other methods . The ad7740 seems like a good choice other than its digital output which is something which I am not familiar with but will hopefully figure out.

Answer (score 4):

There is really little to fear by using a differential amplifier with sufficiently high value resistors, such as 500k, which will limit any possible current to a safe level that will not even be perceptible. The [threshold of perception](http://www.highvoltageconnection.com/articles/ElectricShockQuestions.htm) is generally on the order of one mA, and 5 mA is considered a "safe" level, which is about where most GFCI devices trip.

It is best to use two or three resistors in series, to provide fail-safe redundancy as well as providing good margin for voltage rating of the resistors. So three 150k resistors will limit current to less than 1 mA, and a differential amplifier using a precision op-amp will have good accuracy and common mode rejection. This method can also be used to read phase-to-phase voltages on a motor.

(edit) Aother device to consider is IL300 (Linear Optocoupler).

And you could use a high voltage optoisolator like TLP240GA (400 V) to turn on an isolation amplifier like HCPL-7520 (16 mA) long enough to take a measurement. If the device can start up to take a measurement in 5 ms and a measurement every 100 ms is sufficient, the average current draw would be less than 1 mA. You might be able to assure no more than the rated 400 V by using zener diodes and voltage dividers.

Comment: Done this for a loosely isolated 900 volt supply +1

Comment: Also I think some resistors have UL or safety ratings. Might be best to use those.